# Does anyone know the name, model and year of this car (picture inside)

Tags: car

I have tried to found out the maker, type model of this car but to no avail. 
Could someone help me out.

[image: car 0]

[image: car 1]

[image: car 2]

Sorry for the lousy quality these pictures are from a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtIfwnDnjiM).
Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not about Maintenance & Repair.

Comment: I can delete it if you want me to - if this comments has three upvotes or more i will delete my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 2008-2015 Ford Fiesta. See: 
[Ford_Fiesta#Seventh_generation on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Fiesta#Seventh_generation_(2017%E2%80%93present)_(UK_Mk8))

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a third-generation Ford Escape? Note the grille divider. 2011-2014.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure if it is the ford escape.